# How to sort elements after or before filtering

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
public List<Path> removeUnwantedPaths(List<Path> listofPaths, List<String> ids) {
    List<Path> entries;
    entries = listofPaths.stream()
            .filter(p -> ids.contains(p.getParent().getFileName().toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return entries;
}
```

`entries` contain a list of path element. The elements are not sorted. Im looking to sort them by `ids` returned by `p.getParent().getFileName().toString()` so that the list is organised and sorted before I return the collection. How can I use Java 1.8 `groupingBy()` to group the collection? So If my list contains the following elements initially:

```
212_Hello.txt
312_Hello.txt
516_something.xml
212_Hello.xml
```

I want the list to be organised as:

```
212_Hello.txt
212_Hello.xml
312_Hello.txt
516_something.xml
```

where 212, 312, 516  are the ids.

Comment: Your question is unclear? Do you want to return a `Map<String, List<Path>>`? if not how can you group items in a list? Unless you just want to sort the items (and not group them)?

Comment: so ids are parents' filenames?

Comment: yes so filepaths are like this `/src/resource/files/212/212_Hello.txt`

Comment: Why are you asking for `groupingBy()` when you want to *sort*? Why isn’t looking for `sort()` your first choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do:

```
public static List<Path> removeUnwantedPaths(List<Path> listofPaths, List<String> ids) {
    return listofPaths.stream()
            .filter(p -> ids.contains(getIdFromPath(p)))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> getIdFromPath(p)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static String getIdFromPath(Path p) {
    return p.getParent().getFileName().toString();
}
```

It will:

- filter the given List with elements having an id that is in the given list of authorized ids
- sort the stream according to the id in ascending order
- return a list of that

It is based on the fact that the given paths are always like this: `/src/resource/files/{id}/212_Hello.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not grouping per se, grouping means mapping unique ids to paths. I think what you need is combining both collections. something like this

```
 List<Path> entries;
 entries = listofPaths.stream()
            .filter(p -> ids.contains(p.getParent().getFileName().toString()))
            .map( p -> p.getParent().getFileName() + "_" +p.getFileName())
            .sorted(String::compareTo)
            .map(Paths::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```